# Using fixed elements in responsive design with only css if possible

Tags: css, responsive-design, fixed

This is more a question of logic rather than technical.

I have a design where my header is fixed at the top all the time, so is the footer, but the elements inside have percentage widths so the header will change in size as the window changes.

BUT, as the header is always fixed-positioned the content below is covered by it and as I do not know the height of the header I cannot know how much padding-top I must add to the content so it won't get covered by the header.

What do you say?

Comment: you should also set the padding/margin-top of content in % that is equal to what % you had set as the header height.

Comment: @Froient no, the thing is the header has no defined height, it dependes on the elements inside.

Answer (score 0):

If height goes automatically, you will need js to control it, taking the height of the fixed div and updating top margin/padding dinamically. Anyway, it would be nice if we could see an example of what you have currently